# Undefined index after calling "require_once"

Tags: php

I write this in a page :

```
require_once("pdf/tab_activite.php");
...
foreach ($tab["activite"] as $key => $value) 
{
   ...
}
```

Inside the tab_activite.php there is this :

```
...
$list = new activite($this->db);
$list->lireParNiveau($critere);
$tab["activite"] = $list->tableau ;
...
```

Then in the log there is :

```
[10-Oct-2012 10:30:48] PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  activite in C:\wamp\www\mp\models\objet.class.php on line 543
[10-Oct-2012 10:30:48] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\mp\models\objet.class.php on line 543
```

So how to manipulate correctly the $tab["activite"] variable ?

Comment: Is either of those inside a function?

Comment: Yes , the code `require_once` is inside a function , and the `tab_activite.php` is just lines of codes ( no function ) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `require_once()` is called inside a function, `$tab["activite"]` exists only in that function's scope. Add the statement `global $tab;` to the file `tab_activite.php` before using the `$tab` variable to extend it's scope so that the main program can see it as well.

```
global $tab;
$list = new activite($this->db);
$list->lireParNiveau($critere);
$tab["activite"] = $list->tableau ;
```

**EDIT:** Another problem could occur if you call the function multiple times, as the file is included only once when using `require_once()`. If this is the case, replace `require_once()` with `require()` and see if that helps.

Comment: The log is still the same even after adding the `global $tab;` :)

Comment: @pheromix: Is the `foreach()` inside a function as well? Is it the same function as the `require_once()`?

Comment: Yes they are inside a same function.

Comment: @pheromix: Are you calling the function more than once? See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do a var_dump on $tab["activite"]

```
var_dump($tab["activite"]);
```

If it says nothing, then the variable (or index) doesn't exist and your file has been included in a wrong way (search path?).

Also your error-log hints that your index "activite" doesn't exist, are you sure it's called that? Maybe it's "activate"? Hope this helps.

Comment: var_dump is ok : it shows all the results I want. The index is named activite !

Comment: Is the $tab['activite'] a list?

Comment: If you are getting the information you want, doing a var_dump just before the foreach, it means you don't have any scope-problems and therefor global is excessive. That is at least sorted out this far. Would you mind publishing parts of your var_dump?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `global` for globalizing the `$tab` variable. But many programmers is not advising to use `global` if it is not necessary.

But in your situation I think you have to use `global` for `$tab`

http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: inside function `global $tab;`

Comment: the log is this when I write `global $tab["activite"];` :                [10-Oct-2012 10:49:31] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\mp\models\pdf\tab_activite.php on line 52